Python Selenium getting Error@chrome while using firefox
I am getting this strange error:
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:511:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:136:16

I am using Firefox as Driver.
The code generating the error is quite simple. All I'm trying to do is get all the div of a given class and for each one get the href attribute of the a element inside each div. It works fine when I run the code line by line inside my python interpreter in he command line, but it throws the error when I try to run it inside a function from a script.
Here is the code:
def get_links(class_name):
    profile_divs = self.browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)
    links = []
    for profile in profile_divs:
        try:
            # We get the a tag and append its href attribute to the links list
            a_tag = WebDriverWait(profile, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))
            links.append(a_tag.get_attribute("href"))
        except: # if no a tag is found in the div
            continue
    return(links)

the line that throws the error is
a_tag = WebDriverWait(profile, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'a'))).

But the strange thing is that it works when I run each line individually. I thought it was something related to wait time so I added the
WebDriverWait().until().
But it still doesn't work when trying to use the function.
Any help would be appreciated

argument 1 of WebDriverWait is the driver.  You've passed in an element reference.  You probably want: WebDriverWait(self, 10)? Use profile in your selector or use profile.find_element... to search inside.  Also be sure to have waited long enough for full DOM update to complete before getting profile_divs array.

I tried with profile_divs = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'x1yztbdb'))). This does not throw an error but returns an empty list. I checked the profile_divs list and it only contains one element while it should contain many, all divs with the given class_name. I then added a dumb time.sleep(5) right before and it works. This makes me question the mechanism of WebDriverWait(). I'm guessing it stops as soon as it finds at least one element. Maybe there exists a better condition or maybe making a custom one is a better solution

that's correct, expected condition of ...all elements located by.... will wait until at least 1 element is available.  You should know the DOM is still loading if you get a stale element exception when running a method on one of the elements in the array.  (but a standard sleep is easier...)
